# Who is the singer of "Future Star"?

Tags: music, beyond-the-boundary

Regarding "Future Star" song:

1. Is it right that Kuriyama Mirai or Risa Taneda really sing "Future Star" in *Kyoukai no Kanata* anime by herself (and Nase Mitsuki of course)? Or somebody else did it?
2. Have they performed the dance in the live show at a concert too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true. The voice actors (Risa Taneda, Minori Chihara, and Yuri Yamaoka) themselves sing "Future Star". I mean, the voice even matches in the song and the voice acting of anime.

If you're still skeptical, refer the source below:

- [VGMdb - Beyond the Melodies](https://vgmdb.net/album/42223)
- [Wikia - 
  Kyoukai no Kanata Original Soundtrack "Beyond the Melodies"](http://kyoukainokanata.wikia.com/wiki/Kyoukai_no_Kanata_Original_Soundtrack_%22Beyond_the_Melodies%22)
- [Wikia - Yakusoku no Kizuna](http://kyoukainokanata.wikia.com/wiki/Yakusoku_no_Kizuna)

Also, I am pretty sure voice actors weren't the one dancing in the live show concert. They were some cosplay artists.